# A gentle introduction to harnack curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, textbook-recommendation

I am starting to study Harnack curves and I would like to read a very introductory and intuitive text, if it's possible with a lot of examples and with a clear exposition of general ideas.

Comment: Did you look at articles by Mikhalkin ?